# Why the down votes and no comments for a well researched answer?

Tags: discussion

https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/16689/9069

I understand that with good reason, comments are not required with down votes. I'm asking because I am trying to understand this particular community.

Comment: Pro tip, and maybe I wasn't good at explaining this, but some of us have invested ***massively*** in this site and you might get a better reaction to criticism of old postings by taking a different approach. Provide the good answer and then perhaps suggest that the new information may provide more. Some of us are quite willing to go with that. I'm not worried about reputation loss, it has no effect on my privilege set on the site. However, I think I have earned a certain amount of the benefit of the doubt over time by virtue of my investment here.

Comment: @JohnCavan I have no idea what you mean by "then perhaps suggest that the new information may provide more." There is no benefit of the doubt when knowledge claims are either true or false. Thanks for your effort to make this a great site - likewise, I presume anyone answering questions is doing so for the value the answer adds to the community, but doing so does not make you a "pro" at veterinarian science.

Comment: I really love the effort you've made with this post. Kudos for all the edits and great links. I would love to have upvoted it, I just don't agree with the raw food bit.  I like the way you think and the contributions you make to the site.

Comment: @YvetteColomb thanks for the kind words. As for voting, I am pretty sure SE encourages voting for clear, useful and well researched questions/answers and down voting for unclear, not useful and poorly researched questions/answers instead of whether or not you agree or disagree. So while I strongly encourage you to vote for my answer if you feel it well researched and useful, I'd also encourage you to post an answer which presents your view on raw food as it relates to the question & likewise, I like your moxie here :)

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy yeh, I probably will add an addendum answer. I'm good at doing that. It takes effort though lol

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes it does XD

Answer (score 2):

You have edited the question heavily since it was posted. But...

Original post begins "Consult a veterinarian and/or veterinarian nutritionist"

Current post begins "First and foremost, review this guide"

People come here looking for answers, if your answer starts out telling them to go someplace it is really not a good answer for Pets.SE.

> ..we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about pets. [Tour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour)

Having references is great, but the goal would be for the references to lend support to your answer.  The answer should include important information from the reference (without violating copyright). As opposed to an answer set that says go some place.

When you write your answer, assume that every other resource be it a vet, a web site or a book is not available.  There should be references to support your answer, but the answer should be self contained (internal links to other questions on pets.SE or sister sites count as internal)

There are definitely times when the answer is go to the vet, but those tend to be related to emergent medical issues, bleeding, broken bones, etc.

Related

- [Is consult a vet an appropriate answer?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/is-consult-a-vet-an-appropriate-answer)
- [Should we emphasize the need to go to a vet before a question asking for immediate help is posted?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2134)
- [Should medical emergencies always be off-topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/)

There are others also, but you get the idea. References are where people go to validate you have paraphrased correctly or for more research, they are not where we direct people to. Google directs people here, we give them answers.

Comment: The image just below the opening remark is the list which the pdf goes into greater detail about. This directly addresses the specific question from the OP regarding minerals and vitamins. Would you prefer I transcribed the data?

Comment: Note as well that I do list the items later. Put simply there is not a one size fits all nor a succinct answer to address the general question. Unless you are suggesting that a general question about canine nutrition is out of the sites scope, then an adequate answer will require references to more complete works or simply boil down to: ask your vet about your particular dogs needs.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy you are missing the point, you are opening your answer with **"go some place else"** You can close with follow up else where, but if you open with it, you are making a bad first impression.

Comment: I understand your point about rhetoric, however, I think you are missing the point about actionable information which is included in the answer. Pets.SE is not a substitute for a vet, nor should the internet be.

Comment: Oh. I do think the down-voting is a bit severe given how difficult it is to get "reputation" on SE. One would think a comment about why would be more appropriate. If someone doesn't make the necessary changes, then down-vote the post. The tour is helpful but not definitive in its descriptions of *what not to do*; there are many mods and differing interpretations of what works or fits within each site.

Comment: @M.Mat - Timing is everything. The answer has had 21 edits, the vast majority of which happened after the  down voting. It's a four year old question, though, and so re-visits are not all that common as a result, though James may choose to switch his vote at this point. Frankly, it's a far better answer than mine, but I'm waiting to see the courtesy I requested as a very long time user and a moderator to actually manifest before I cast my vote and, quite possibly, delete my own, quite old, answer.