# Is a canonical question about free/low/deferred veterinary costs would be a good idea

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

There seem to be a number of questions where the correct response (usually as a comment) is 'Consult a vet' possibly with 'urgently' tagged on.

Would it be sensible to have a canonical question with answers giving details of free/low cost sources of veterinary assistance (by country), so that the information is easily available to people for whom the cost may be a deterrent to them getting the help they need?

Here in the UK for example we have the PDSA and Blue Cross charities.

We could also possibly include information about how to defer the costs of treatment?

Related Meta Posts

- [Is consult a vet an appropriate answer?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319)
- [Should we emphasize the need to go to a vet before a question asking for immediate help is posted?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2134)
- [Should medical emergencies always be off-topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798)

Answer (score 3):

I have posted the question [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options)

I included the statement below

> *This a general question per the meta post Is a canonical question about free/low/deferred veterinary costs would be a good idea Optimally there will be one answer per country (or multiple countries per answer if they share a soluition)*

Comment: Do we really want one answer per country so that some are voted higher than others? Is there any reason the UK answer should be higher than France’s? I would think that it would be better to have a single community wiki answer. That would also avoid the awkward situation of having competing answers from users for the same country.

Comment: @Thunderforge There are limits on the number of characters that one answer can contain.  As the number of countries increase one answer would not be sufficient.  The answer now includes an alphabetized list with links in the question to specific country answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a great idea.. I would expect many wouldn't be aware of such resources and if we can help them in that regard it has the potential to be very valuable.